# Change DBase On Run Time C# app

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

I have developed an accounting program that is working beautifully, but now a new need has arisen.
When I enter the program, by default it reads the DB that I put in the file `WinSCM.exe.config` and if I want to change I have to exit the program and edit the file changing the DB name.

I did not want it to be this way, because my client does accounting for several companies and each company is a DB, so I wanted a way to select a company and when selecting this company the database is automatically changed in the release version.

I'm using Entity Framework to connect to Sql Server DB

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can create a form which should be opened first when the application starts and asks for the Company selection. You need to store the company name and its db connection string in some file such as xml file and display companies in the form from the XML file. Once Company is selected you need to set the appropriate connection string in a application level global variable and use that to initialize the EntityFramework context.

Comment: Thanks buddy
I followed your proposal and it's working beautifully. is however a situation literally resolved because it does not completely satisfy my client. He wants to switch the DBs within the program, during operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what reading your DB is, but normally when you use Entity Framework you create a DbContext object whenever you need to do a query, or at utmost a few queries. You are not supposed to keep this DbContext alive for longer periods of time, say more than a few seconds. A minute would be very rare.

Whenever you create the Dbcontext instance you could use the default constructor that uses the config file to get the connection string to the database.

However [one of the other constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.) let you define the connection string to the database in the constructor. So if you want to construct your DbContext and connect it to a different database, just use that constructor

If you don't know the connection string, but you have a DbConnection to the database, there will be even a constructor for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everybody Thank alot for your Answer. I just Solved My Question like this:

Fisrt of all, I created a class wich I called ConnetionTolls with this Content://.

```
public static class ConnectionTools
    {
        // all params are optional
        public static void ChangeDatabase(
            this DbContext source,
            string initialCatalog = "",
            string dataSource = "",
            string userId = "",
            string password = "",
            bool integratedSecuity = true,
            string configConnectionStringName = "")
        /* this would be used if the
        *  connectionString name varied from 
        *  the base EF class name */
        {
            try
            {
                // use the const name if it's not null, otherwise
                // using the convention of connection string = EF contextname
                // grab the type name and we're done
                var configNameEf = string.IsNullOrEmpty(configConnectionStringName)
                    ? source.GetType().Name
                    : configConnectionStringName;
            // add a reference to System.Configuration
            var entityCnxStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings[configNameEf].ConnectionString);

            // init the sqlbuilder with the full EF connectionstring cargo
            var sqlCnxStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                (entityCnxStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);

            // only populate parameters with values if added
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialCatalog))
                sqlCnxStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource))
                sqlCnxStringBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                sqlCnxStringBuilder.UserID = userId;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                sqlCnxStringBuilder.Password = password;

            // set the integrated security status
            sqlCnxStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = integratedSecuity;

            // now flip the properties that were changed
            source.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
                = sqlCnxStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // set log item if required
        }
    }
```

********the way to use it is like this***************

//I use this method in a diferent Class
//This method returns the Entity i use with new connections

```
    public static MyEntities SelectDb(String DataBase,String sqlUser,String pw, String serverInstance){

        var selectedDbase = new MyEntities();
        // so only reference the changed properties
        // using the object parameters by name
        selectedDbase.ChangeDatabase
            (
                initialCatalog: DataBase,
                userId: sqlUser,
                password: pw,
                dataSource: serverInstance// could be ip address 100.23.45.67 etc
            );
        return selectedDbase;

    }
```

I want to thank everyone here and on other forums because this was the result of Your Contributions